# python selenium : change chrome download location during runtime?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using python selenium chrome webdriver to download files from a website to a specific download location.

currently:

I'm initiating the driver with required download location using chromeOptions prefs , download the file , close the driver instance then repeating the same process to download another file to different location.

```
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    prefs = {"download.default_directory": file_path}
    chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

    # opening webdriver
    chromedriver = chromedriver_path
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, chrome_options=chromeOptions)

    print("Download location changed to  " + file_path)
```

Requirement:

Since i have to Change-Start-Close again and again to download files from same website.
Is there any way to dynamically change the download location path after dowloading the first file without closing the current webdriver instance.

Comment: Could you, rather than trying to change the location it downloads to, instead just download it then move the file from the download directory to wherever you want it to be?

Comment: thanks...Its easier than i thought